# Java swing GUI form/jFrame, average , largest and smallest button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

**A user is prompt to enter 6 integer number in the form (text Field). So far I have done the average. How do I create the code for largest and smallest number?**

---

```
private void averageButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;
    int number3 = 0;
    int number4 = 0;
    int number5 = 0;
    int number6 = 0; 

    try {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(
        this.oneTextField1.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bad first number", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    try {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(
        this.twoTextField2.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bad number 2", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    try {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(
        this.threeTextField3.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bad number 3", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    try {
        number4 = Integer.parseInt(
        this.fourTextField4.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bad number 4", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    try {
        number5 = Integer.parseInt(
        this.fiveTextField5.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bad number 5", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    try {
        number6 = Integer.parseInt(
        this.sixTextField6.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Bad number 6", "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    int answer = (number1 + number2+number3+number4+number5+number6)/6;
    this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);
```

Comment: Always best to show us your attempt to solve this with your question. Please fix this.

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Start by writing the code to decide which is larger: number1 or number2.

Comment: int answer = (number1);
        this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);   
        if (number1<number2)
                answer =(number2);
        this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);

Comment: Thank you for the hint to gave me. I am very new in programming and I am trying to learn by myself. This is not homework or any way I am trying to make more complex my homework. This is the first time when I am working with Java swing GUI form/jFrame. 
The question is can I use for loop?

Comment: I have used "if" but I get only to test the first two numbers. Now, I do not know how to use else if statement as the answer after using else if it returns me  0 as answer.

Comment: int answer = (number1);
        this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);   
        if (number1<number2)
                answer =(number2);
        this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);   
        else if  (number2<number3);
        answer = (number3);

Comment: Never mind. I solved out.

Answer (score 0):

```
int answer = (number1);
    this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);   
    if (number1<number2)
            answer =(number2);

   else if (number2 < number3)
                {
                 answer=number3;
           }
    this.answerLabel1.setText("The answer is: " +answer);
```